# Problems Installing pdf-tools on MacOs - ARM64

Tags: osx, pdf-tools

I have problems getting pdf-tools to run on Emacs (from railwaycat) on MacOs - ARM64 i.e. on Apple Silicon.

```
GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 1, aarch64-apple-darwin21.6.0, Carbon Version 165 AppKit 2113.6) of 2023-08-08
```

I installed the pdf-tools without problems (via the drop-down-menu)

```
    pdf-tools   1.1.0   installed    Support library for PDF documents
```

but when I execute the standard activation command

```
 (pdf-tools-install)
```

which tries to compile the poppler server, I get warnings and linker errors:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.dylib, 
building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64

 [...]

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [epdfinfo] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
===========================
 Build failed.  ;o(    
===========================
```

Any ideas how can get the compiler to link with ARM64 dynlibs or how to provide/create these?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: With my previous setup I had to use `echo export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig >> ~/.bash_profile` to install 'pdf-tools'. But that was in the past. Also see [Improved way to install pdf-tools on M1 Macs?](https://github.com/vedang/pdf-tools/issues/107) & [Cannot install pdf-tools on macOS](https://github.com/vedang/pdf-tools/issues/70).

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know how did you install that Emacs
version. Taking into account the error messages, you have somewhere a wrong
Emacs version. I suggest to use `brew`, it will install/compile from
sources, so here are some steps to follow to have success:

- remove your actual Emacs installation
- install macOS command line tools, with `xcode-select --install`
- install `brew` from [this page](https://wwww.brew.sh) (needs previous item)
- in your terminal type `brew tap railwaycat/emacsmacport`
- optional `brew info emacs-mac` to see all dependencies that will be installed
- now `brew install emacs-mac --with-modules`

The installation process will download the source code, will apply some
patches (I guess you did not do that step), and then usual autoconfig, make,
make-install will follow (~5 min).

Once you have that, start Emacs from `/opt/homebrew/opt/emacs-mac/Emacs.app`,
and then install `pdf-tools`.

Note: I tested yesterday the above steps, `pdf-tools` installs and work OK, M1 machine.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks  a lot for the detailed description. It's good to know you got it working on Apple Silicon. I'll try it as soon as I find the time and report back.

Comment: Just tried it, works like a charm! :-) Thanks a lot!

PS: For other readers: I had to install PDF tools after installing Emacs:


M-x package-install <RET> pdf-tools

M-x pdf-tools-install

Comment: Then mark the question as answered, please.